# Select * from view more than 10x slower than executing the views create statement directly with MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have created a view as a join of several tables to hide the complexity.

Now when I execute a `select * from view` it takes more than 10x of the execution time it takes to execute the select statement directly, that defines the view (about 70 ms vs 900 ms).

This behaviour occurs on a MySQL 5.7.23 server.

I compared the execution plans for both queries and the only difference (as expected) is the derived table:
[image]

Is this a normal behaviour of views or how can I fix it?

P.S.:
The create view statement as requested (names where obfuscated):

```
create view vrs as select
rs."id" as "id",
l."language" as "language",
rss."t" as "discriminator",
rss."type" as "type",
coalesce(lt3."text", concat('!',s3."textkey",'(',l."language",')')) as "typeText",
rss."model" as "model",
coalesce(lt2."text", concat('!',s2."textkey",'(',l."language",')')) as "modelText",
rs."name"  as "name",
rs."reqCATGroup" as "CATGroup",
rs."devID" as "devID",
case s."builtIn"
    when 0 then s."displayName"
    else (select lt1."text"
        from loctext lt1
        where lt1."language"=l."language"
        and lt1."textkey"=s."displayName")
end as "sName",
s."id" as "sId",
s."postcode" as "sPostcode",
s."place" as "sPlace",
s."street" as "sStreet",
s."streetNumber" as "sStreetNumber",
s."tId" as "tId",
t."tName" as "tName",
rss."CCVMajor" as "CCVMajor",
rss."CCVMinor" as "CCVMinor",
rss."CCVPatch" as "CCVPatch",
rss."CCHV" as "CCHV",
coalesce(lHw."text", concat('!',sHw."textkey",'(',l."language",')')) as "CCHVText",
rss."MCVMajor" as "MCVMajor",
rss."MCVMinor" as "MCVMinor",
rss."MCVPatch" as "MCVPatch",
rss."level",
coalesce(lLevel."text", concat('!', sLevel."textkey", '(', l."language", ')')) as "levelText",
rss."event",
coalesce(lEvent."text", concat('!', sEvent."textkey", '(', l."language", ')')) as "eventText",
rss."isBusy" as "isBusy",
rss."tsLastComIn" as "tsLastCom",
rss."tsBT" AS "tsBT",
b1."ordinal" as "isSending",
coalesce(ltSend."text", concat('!',b1."textkey",'(',l."language",')')) as "isSendingText",
b2."ordinal" as "isReceiving",
coalesce(ltReceive."text", concat('!',b2."textkey",'(',l."language",')')) as "isReceivingText",
rs."historyCreateDevTs",
rs."historyCreateDevUserId",
rs."historyCreateDevUserLoginName",
rs."historyModifyDevLinkTs",
rs."historyModifyDevLinkUserId",
rs."historyModifyDevLinkUserLoginName",
rs."monitorStartTs",
rs."monitorEndTs"
from synch rss
cross join loclanguages l
join cfgrs rs on rs."id" = rss."id"
join cfgs s on s."id" = rs."sId"
join cfgt t on t."id" = s."tId"
left join locmodel s2 on s2."ordinal" = rss."model"
left join loctext lt2 on lt2."textkey" = s2."textkey" and lt2."language" = l."language"
left join loctype s3 on s3."ordinal" = rss."type"
left join loctext lt3 on lt3."textkey" = s3."textkey" and lt3."language" = l."language"
left join locbooleanrange b1 on rs."sending"+1 = b1."ordinal"
left join loctext ltSend on ltSend."textkey" = b1."textkey" and ltSend."language" = l."language"
left join locbooleanrange b2 on rs."receiving"+1 = b2."ordinal"
left join loctext ltReceive on ltReceive."textkey" = b2."textkey" and ltReceive."language" = l."language"
left join loceventlevel sLevel on sLevel."ordinal" = rss."level"
left join loctext lLevel on lLevel."textkey" = sLevel."textkey" and lLevel."language" = l."language"
left join locevent sEvent on sEvent."ordinal" = rss."event" and sEvent."type" = rss."type"
left join loctext lEvent on lEvent."textkey" = sEvent."textkey" and lEvent."language" = l."language"
left join loccchv sHw on sHw."ordinal" = rss."CCHV"
left join loctext lHw on lHw."textkey" = sHw."textkey" and lHw."language" = l."language"
where rs."deleted" = 0
;
```

P.P.S.: The complete execution plans look like this:

direct call:
[image: direct call]

view:
[image]

Comment: are You sure You used the same queries as view and direct ?

Comment: Yes, I used the create view script and removed the "create view xy as" part.

Comment: try recreating the view with [ALGORITHM = MERGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html)   what merge tries to do is rewrite the view query into a query you used in the `CREATE VIEW .. AS (<query>)`  part.. It's better explained in the link i've provided

Comment: when trying to create the view using the algorithm (create
 ALGORITHM = MERGE
 view xy as select...) I get a warning "Error number: 1354 Message: View merge algorithm can't be used here for now (assumed undefined algorithm)". The view gets created, but I don't know if the algorithm is used.

Comment: Post the complete `CREATE VIEW ... AS ...` code in the question.. "Error number: 1354 Message: View merge algorithm can't be used here for now (assumed undefined algorithm)" i have a feeling you are using aggregate functions in the View?

Comment: I added the create statement. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Only functions used are "coalesce" and "concat", do these count as aggregate functions?
Besides the fact that we select many columns from many join tables, the view should be straight forward.
The confusing size of the script was the reason why I decided to not share it in the first place. ;)

Comment: Why do you use a cross join and why don't you post the whole explain output? You successfully cut the relevant information there.

Comment: I use a cross join to insert every available language from loclanguages to every row from synch. This is used for translation.
I haven't posted the complete outputs, because they match identically (despite the snippet i posted originally). As there is no problem with the direct call, I thought I reduce the question to the "relevant", to not overload the question.
But I have no hurt feeling when you prove me wrong now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This link is for MySQL 8.0, but when I last had performance issues with Views in MySQL 5.6, 5.7, and went digging, I got the same answer: You basically cannot take advantage of Indexes when using Views.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html

I personally found Views in MySQL to Not be useful overall, due to limitations like the ones described above, particularly due to the performance hit.

Readers - if somehow Views in MySQL can perform, I certainly missed a key memo somewhere. Please correct me if this is the case.

Comment: In my case there should be no need for using an index on the view, because this behaviour happens even without any "where", "group by" ... conditions. So practically the same statement should be executed. Only difference i found is the creation of a derived table, while querying the view.

Comment: Please refrain from generalizing! Views work quite well and I've never had issues with them. And the link you provided states, that you can not create an index on a view. But of course indexes are used, when you create them on the tables your view is reading.